# Can I run an ftp script on a web host?

Tags: web, ftp, web-hosting

I am trying to make a monitoring program that uses sensors, the organization who owns the sensor and the server where the sensor sends data to is generous enough to give me ftp access to their web server. What I need to do now is constantly run an ftp script to automatically get the files from their server every 15 minutes since the sensor sends new data every 15 mins. I will then need to upload the downloaded data to my website to display the new values.

My question is: do I need to run a computer that will run the scripts needed to do these or can I upload an ftp script to my web host of my website where I will upload the files do this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your webhost. If the web host support it, you can run a cronjob that calls your ftp script periodically and does al the actions (fetching file, writing to other file etc.).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.

Answer (score -1):

You need to load a php file every 15 minutes using CRON http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/.

The php file can then do ftp using CURL http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php, writting the results to a database, which can then be read by another script to display the results when requested

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've read the page about CURL but i'm not sure if it's available in my web host. How can I check if it's available, and if it's not, how do I install it? Do I have to request it to my web host?

Comment: Type in phpinfo() to see your sever configuration- if you don't see anything about curl, or it is disabled you can't use curl